# Unity - same turn radius of an object with different speeds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I have an simple circle that can move with script:

```
public float speed = 3f;
public float rotationSpeed = 200f;

private float horizontal = 0f;

void Update()
{
    horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, Space.Self);
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * -horizontal * rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

The problem is that I want to keep same turn radius with different speed.
Now when I am increasing speed also turn radius is getting bigger:

[image: like here]

How can I do this? Do I have to use some kind of ratio to increase speed and rotationSpeed?

Comment: A complete code example reproducing the error would help.

Comment: I manually change speed value (for example from 3f to 5f). In the future it will be gaining speed with time

Comment: This is a question relating to calculus... In essence you'll have to calculate how the rate of rotation changes with respect to velocity to keep the radius constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main ways to approach this. First, you could calculate the differential equation for the rate of change of rotation speed with respect to velocity to keep the radius constant, then solve this for the rotation speed. The second, and perhaps easier way is as follows:

The distance the particle has to travel is constant, assuming a semi circular path, this is equal to `pi*r`, else, it is `(theta/2pi)2pi*r`.

Consequently, we can calculate the travel time of the object to be equal to the distance divided by its tangential velocity, giving `(pi*r)/V`.

Finally, your rate of turn is equal to the 2*pi divided by the time you need the turn to take, which gives `R = 2Vpi/pi*r rads^-1`. Which cancels down to `2Vr rads^-1`.

I'm not certain of the exact details of how to implement it but it would look something like this:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    const int radius = 10;
    rotationSpeed = 2 * speed * radius;
    transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, Space.Self);
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * -horizontal * rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

Although it's almost certainly worth checking my maths as I haven't done this sort of thing for a while.

There is a third significantly less graceful way where you calculate the `Vector3 position` for many points along the parabola that is your path and move to the next one every `FixedUpdate()`. You can then just alter the `dx` such that it is larger for faster velocities and smaller for slower ones. This has the advantage of being very easy to implement, but it totally destroys the physics of the application, if that matters.

Comment: No worries! As a side note, it might be worth exposing the radius, or not having it as a `const` if you wish to be able to change it at runtime. Oh, and welcome to SO!